# How to pass multiple variables from one functional component to other in React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've tried to pass multiple variables from one functional component to other react components. But every time I'm getting an error.

Here's the code of component `Sports.js` from where I'm trying to pass the value.

Sports.js

```
// initiallising states
const [items1, setItems1] = useState({
pageCount: '',
field_names_state: [],
toggle: false,
elements: [],
data_form: [],
sports_id: '',
buttonEnable: '1',
});

// map our fetched data and send it to Table_Sports.js

const data1 = items1.elements.map((item) => (
<Table_Sports key={item.sports_id} item={item} action={onRadioChange} />
));
```

Table_Sports.js

```
      <td>
        <input
          type='radio'
          // defaultValue={props.item.sports_id}
          defaultValue={props.}
          name='sports_id'
          onClick={(e) => props.action(e)}
        />
      </td>

      <td>
        <input
          type='text'
          defaultValue={props.item.sports_name}
          name='sports_name'
          contentEditable='true'
        />
      </td>
```

Here I'm getting all mapped data for all `elements` except `buttonEnable`.
How can I get the value of `buttonEnable` as well?

Comment: I don’t understand; you’re mapping “elements”, you’re not passing anything else from your state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work to send the `buttonEnable` prop to your `Table_Sports`.
But I'm not sure what are you trying to do, since `elements` has a `length === 0`

```
const data1 = items1.elements.map((item) => (
  <Table_Sports
    key={item.sports_id}
    item={item}
    action={onRadioChange}
    buttonEnable={items1.buttonEnable}
  />
));
```

Then, get it with:

```
<input
  type='radio'
  // defaultValue={props.item.sports_id}
  defaultValue={props.}
  name='sports_id'
  onClick={(e) => props.action(e)}
  // HERE
  disabled={props.buttonEnable !== '1'}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are mapping `items1.elements.map((item)` although item in items1.elements doens't contain the buttonEnable property, to pass buttonEnable property to child component simply just add one more prop `<Table_Sports isButtonEnable isButtonEnable={item1.buttonEnable} />` along with rest props.